# JSF h:commandButton doesn't fire with ajax

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

This is the relevant part of my code (I am trying to add a timetable component to my school's portal):

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="sc-timetable-slots" styleClass="traverse ui-helper-clearfix">
                    <h:form id="sc-timetable-slots-table" styleClass="sc-left-bulk ui-widget-content">
                        <div class="sc-8-column">
                            <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="sc-hours">
                                <ul>
                                    <li class="ui-widget-header"><h:outputText value="H" /></li>
                                    <c:forEach begin="4" end="24" var="h">
                                        <li>#{h}:00</li>
                                    </c:forEach> 
                                </ul>
                            </h:panelGroup>
                        </div>
                        <ui:repeat value="#{timetableSlot.dow}" var="dow" varStatus="ix">
                            <div class="sc-8-column">
                                <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="sc-timetable-slots">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li class="ui-widget-header"><h:outputText value="#{msg[dow]}"/></li>
                                        <ui:repeat value="#{timetableSlot.getSlots(login.person,ix.index)}" var="slot">
                                            <li class="sc-timetable-item">
                                                <h:commandLink action="#{timetableSlot.edit(slot)}" value="#{slot.timeStart} : #{slot.timeEnd}" styleClass="sc-button incomplete">
                                                    <f:ajax render=":sc-timetable-slots" onevent="reRender"/>
                                                </h:commandLink>
                                            </li>
                                        </ui:repeat>
                                        <li>
                                            <h:commandLink action="#{timetableSlot.edit(login.person,ix.index)}" value="#{msg['timetable.slots.new']}" styleClass="sc-button incomplete">
                                                <f:ajax render=":sc-timetable-slots" onevent="reRender"/>
                                            </h:commandLink>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </h:panelGroup>
                            </div>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </h:form>
                    <h:form id="sc-timetable-slots-edit" styleClass="sc-right-detail ui-widget-content" rendered="#{not empty timetableSlot.edited}">
                        <span class="traverse ui-widget-header">#{msg['timetable.slots.edit']}</span> 
                        <h:panelGrid styleClass="traverse" columns="2">
                            <h:outputLabel for="timeStart" value="#{msg['timetable.slots.start']}"/>
                            <h:inputText id="timeStart" value="#{timetableSlot.edited.timeStart}"/>
                            <h:outputLabel for="timeEnd" value="#{msg['timetable.slots.end']}"/>
                            <h:inputText id="timeEnd" value="#{timetableSlot.edited.timeEnd}"/>
                            <h:commandButton type="submit" styleClass="sc-button incomplete" action="#{timetableSlot.save}" value="#{msg['nav.save']}">
                                <f:ajax render=":sc-timetable-slots" onevent="reRender"/>
                            </h:commandButton>
                        </h:panelGrid>                            
                    </h:form>
                </h:panelGroup>
```

The commandLinks work fine, but the "save" commandButton doesn't. It's not the "rendered" attribute, I tried without it, same. The thing is, it doesn't fire at all, no XHR gets generated, the button is dead. I tried different combinations, even setting the "render" attribute to "@all". Still nothing. The last time I asked about something involving commandButton and ajax, I was in a hurry so I worked around it eventually - but this time I'd like to get to the bottom of it. :D

Comment: To exclude one and other: does it work on second click? What scope is the managed bean in?

Comment: I have a break point in the "save" method, on the first line. It never reaches that. The managed bean is in view scope.

Comment: Does it also fail when you request a fresh page and don't use any of the other commandlinks? I.e. first open the page by a fresh GET and then immediately click save button? (you should remove the `rendered` attribute in order to try this test)

Comment: it works, in the sense that it gives an error  javax.faces.el.EvaluationException, which is expected because it needs to set properties on a null object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I haven't tried to reproduce this locally because it's too much code and not SSCCE-worthy

However, I know that when you have multiple ajax forms which render each other by a general/common parent ID, then any submit of the *other* form on a subsequent request will fail because the view state is not appended as a hidden field after re-render by JS. But, if that was the case, then a second attempt to submit it should actually work. Perhaps there is more into the story, but to start, you need to explicitly specify the ID of the *other* form in the `render` attribute of the `<f:ajax>`.

Do it for the both `<f:ajax>` tags inside the first form:

```html
<f:ajax render=":sc-timetable-slots :sc-timetable-slots-edit" onevent="reRender"/>
```

In your particular case, the `:sc-timetable-slots-edit` is the ID of the *other* form.

#### See also:

- [Ajax rendering of content which contains another form](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichContainsAnotherForm)

Comment: Thanks a lot - I'll give it a try. The thing that's killing me though is that I have no way of debugging it, no error, neither @ js, nor @ Java side.

Comment: You should track ajax request/response in for example Firebug. You should have noticed that the view state parameter is missing.

Comment: I did now, knowing what to look for :D If I configure JSF to save state on server, would that have any influence on this matter, or am I just sailing on cold waters?

Comment: No, state saving method should not matter. It's the JSF-supplied `jsf.js` file who's to blame here. Did my proposed suggestion work?

Comment: Yes. Please, run for president! :D